# Batch Update Exception, wrong syntax used near INSERT statement at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

Seems the syntax is fine but don't know what to do? Kindly figure it out.

Here is one of the line to be inserted: **INSERT INTO SmartMiner ( Outlook VARCHAR(64),Temp VARCHAR(64),Humidity VARCHAR(64),Windy VARCHAR(64),Play VARCHAR(64) ) VALUES ('sunny,hot,high,false,no')**

Exception: **java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(64),Temp VARCHAR(64),Humidity VARCHAR(64),Windy VARCHAR(64),Play VARCHAR' at line 1**

```
    public void FileRead(String st, String tableName) {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String sql = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(st);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    for(int x=0;x<tokens.length;x++){
        System.out.println(tokens[x]);
    }

    setConnection();

    //connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    stmt = connection.createStatement();

    DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet resultSet;
    resultSet = metadata.getTables(null, null, "tableName", null);
    if(resultSet!=null){
      // next() checks if the next table exists ...
         System.out.println("Table exists");

        sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName;
        System.out.println("sql :" + sql);
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }


    String query = "";
    String comma = "";

    for (String token : tokens) {
    query += comma + token;
    comma = ",";
    }
    sql = "CREATE TABLE SmartMiner (" + query + ")";
    System.out.println("sql :" + sql);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    line = br.readLine();
    if(line != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    while (line != null) {
    sql = "INSERT INTO "+tableName+"("+query+")"+"VALUES("+line+")";
    System.out.println("sql :" + sql);
    stmt.addBatch(sql);
    line = br.readLine();
    }

    stmt.executeBatch();
    //connection.commit();
    closeConnection();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`VALUES ('sunny,hot,high,false,no')` - this is completely incorrect. This is **one** textual field, instead of 5. given the number of columns mentioned after the table name.

It should be:

`VALUES ('sunny','hot','high','false','no')`.

You need to fix the logic for what generates your `VALUES` clause (that is, your `line` variable). It seems to just read a line from a file, but either that line is not formatted correctly, or you are expected to do more work on parsing it and building up the query.